# SQLAlchemy - don't enforce foreign key constraint on a relationship

Tags: python, sql-server, join, foreign-keys, sqlalchemy

I have a `Test` model/table and a `TestAuditLog` model/table, using SQLAlchemy and SQL Server 2008.  The relationship between the two is `Test.id == TestAuditLog.entityId`, with one test having many audit logs.  `TestAuditLog` is intended to keep a history of changes to rows in the `Test` table.  I want to track when a `Test` is deleted, also, but I'm having trouble with this.  In SQL Server Management Studio, I set the `FK_TEST_AUDIT_LOG_TEST` relationship's "[Enforce Foreign Key Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177288.aspx)" property to "No", thinking that would allow a `TestAuditLog` row to exist with an `entityId` that no longer connects to any `Test.id` because the `Test` has been deleted.  However, when I try to create a `TestAuditLog` with SQLAlchemy and then delete the `Test`, I get an error:

> (IntegrityError) ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AL_TEST_ID', table 'TEST_AUDIT_LOG'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)") u'UPDATE [TEST_AUDIT_LOG] SET [AL_TEST_ID]=? WHERE [TEST_AUDIT_LOG].[AL_ID] = ?' (None, 8)

I think because of the foreign-key relationship between `Test` and `TestAuditLog`, after I delete the `Test` row, SQLAlchemy is trying to update all that test's audit logs to have a `NULL` `entityId`.  I don't want it to do this; I want SQLAlchemy to leave the audit logs alone.  How can I tell SQLAlchemy to allow audit logs to exist whose `entityId` does not connect with any `Test.id`?

I tried just removing the `ForeignKey` from my tables, but I'd like to still be able to say `myTest.audits` and get all of a test's audit logs, and SQLAlchemy complained about not knowing how to join `Test` and `TestAuditLog`.  When I then specified a `primaryjoin` on the `relationship`, it grumbled about not having a `ForeignKey` or `ForeignKeyConstraint` with the columns.

Here are my models:

```
class TestAuditLog(Base, Common):
    __tablename__ = u'TEST_AUDIT_LOG'
    entityId = Column(u'AL_TEST_ID', INTEGER(), ForeignKey(u'TEST.TS_TEST_ID'),
        nullable=False)
    ...

class Test(Base, Common):
    __tablename__ = u'TEST'
    id = Column(u'TS_TEST_ID', INTEGER(), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    audits = relationship(TestAuditLog, backref="test")
    ...
```

And here's how I'm trying to delete a test while keeping its audit logs, their `entityId` intact:

```
    test = Session.query(Test).first()
    Session.begin()
    try:
        Session.add(TestAuditLog(entityId=test.id))
        Session.flush()
        Session.delete(test)
        Session.commit()
    except:
        Session.rollback()
        raise
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can solve this by:

- **POINT-1:** not having a `ForeignKey` neither on the `RDBMS` level nor on the SA level
- **POINT-2:** explicitly specify join conditions for the relationship
- **POINT-3:** mark relationship cascades to rely on [passive_deletes](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html?highlight=passive_deletes#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) flag

Fully working code snippet below should give you an idea (**points** are highlighted in the `code`):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

class TestAuditLog(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TEST_AUDIT_LOG'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    comment = Column(String)

    entityId = Column('TEST_AUDIT_LOG', Integer, nullable=False,
                     # POINT-1
                     #ForeignKey('TEST.TS_TEST_ID', ondelete="CASCADE"),
                     )

    def __init__(self, comment):
        self.comment = comment

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<TestAuditLog(id=%s entityId=%s, comment=%s)>" % (self.id, self.entityId, self.comment)

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TEST'
    id = Column('TS_TEST_ID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    audits = relationship(TestAuditLog, backref='test',
                # POINT-2
                primaryjoin="Test.id==TestAuditLog.entityId",
                foreign_keys=[TestAuditLog.__table__.c.TEST_AUDIT_LOG],
                # POINT-3
                passive_deletes='all',
            )

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Test(id=%s, name=%s)>" % (self.id, self.name)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

###################
## tests
session = Session()

# create test data
tests = [Test("test-" + str(i)) for i in range(3)]
_cnt = 0
for _t in tests:
    for __ in range(2):
        _t.audits.append(TestAuditLog("comment-" + str(_cnt)))
        _cnt += 1
session.add_all(tests)
session.commit()
session.expunge_all()
print '-'*80

# check test data, delete one Test
t1 = session.query(Test).get(1)
print "t: ", t1
print "t.a: ", t1.audits
session.delete(t1)
session.commit()
session.expunge_all()
print '-'*80

# check that audits are still in the DB for deleted Test
t1 = session.query(Test).get(1)
assert t1 is None
_q = session.query(TestAuditLog).filter(TestAuditLog.entityId == 1)
_r = _q.all()
assert len(_r) == 2
for _a in _r:
    print _a
```

**Another option** would be to duplicate the column used in the FK, and make the FK column nullable with `ON CASCADE SET NULL` option. In this way you can still check the audit trail of deleted objects using this column.

Comment: The `passive_deletes='all'` on the `relationship` did it!  That way I was able to keep the relationships and SQLAlchemy didn't go back and try to wipe out the `entityId` on `Test` deletion.  Thanks!

Comment: Just for the reference - it would be required to also set `lazy="dynamic"` on parent side of relationship so sqlalchemy won't fetch all children when you do not need it (i.e. when only updating an unrelevant field in parent table).

Comment: @Greg0ry: No, you do not need to. As documented in [Using Loader Strategies: Lazy Loading, Eager Loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-loader-strategies-lazy-loading-eager-loading): *By default, all inter-object relationships are lazy loading...*. So unless you do otherwise, parent should not load children unless you access them.

Comment: @van - my observation was different when using sqlalchemy in Pylons Pyramid - only explicit `lasy="dynamic"` on relationship was preventing sqlalchemy from fetching children of parent that was being updated.

Comment: Interesting, maybe your code accesses the children for some reason? Count or print out, or any other reason?

Comment: @van - I have simple database handling (nothing fancy, simple models with relationships configured the way you was very kind to describe here). I have run some debugs and aparently children are not fetched after I have set `lazy="dynamic"` (I suppose if I was doing something to fetch children objects `lazy="dynamic"` would not result in children not being fetched).

Comment: @Greg0ry: in the code of the answer the model does not have any `lazy=...`. If after first line with `print '-'*80` you do the following `t1 = session.query(Test).get(1);
session.delete(t1);
session.commit()`, you will see that the children (`TestAuditLog`) are not loaded. So it must be something else in your code that makes it load. I suggest you post another question with the self-contained sample code which shows the issue.

Comment: @van - try updating within an before_flush event. I have no issue with adding lazy="dynamic" and in my case after adding this to my relationship everything works as expected - so I have no issue that need solving :-) for the sake of my own curiosity I have run the very same model outside from pyramid and lazy="dynamic" was not needed - my guess is there is something pyramid does with transactions but that is not something I have time to investigate further. I posted my advice to people who may find the same strange behavior when using sqlalchemy within pylons pyramid, that's all :-)

Comment: @SarahVessels My question too, thanks for asking! Can you confirm that the only thing you changed was the `passive_delete` flag? I have a SA FK constraint that isn't actually in the RDBMS and setting `passive_delete` seemed to fix the problems I was having